# PowerBI recursion calculation using Dax or Power query - Each row column value needs to refer previous row same column value

Tags: powerbi

I have requirement where I have to apply formula which refers itself (recursive). Each column needs to be refer to previous row column value.
Please find attached excel sheet for formula reference. I need to calculate calc_amt field.
Please check formula used. Field refers itself for index 1 onwards for each uid.
For each uid, eff_date repeats.

Any help here would be great
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBaae.jpg[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBaae.jpg%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sFS8.jpg)

Ron, sorry I was out of town and sorry for the delayed response.
I wanted to attach the excel sheet with formula but looks excel attachment is not allowed. I have attached the image again taken from excel. Column K has the formula. For index 1 and above, column refers itself. This repeats for each uid.

Comment: In Power Query you can refer easily to the previous row by using either `List.Generate` or by adding a column to the table that is shifted by one row from the original.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Is there way it can be achieved through DAX formula? Do you have Power query sample code for achieving this recursion

Comment: I don't know enough about DAX to tell you the possibilities. So far as PQ code, it is not clear what you want. You mention "recursion" and you mention "formula referring to previous row. Those are two different things.  You also do not provide information and data to reproduce the problem you are having. You provided a screenshot of data. What program do you use to convert this to usable data for Power BI?